# How to pass a std::function or a function pointer into qtconnect?

Tags: c++, qt, function-pointers, qt-connection

This is mainly to clean up a bunch of code from my constructor. I have around 20+ lines of `connect(object, func1, this, func2)` in the constructor alone and I am trying to clean up the code by having a `std::vector<std::tuple<QObject*,std::function<void()>,std::function<void>>>> connections;`

It would work out quite nicely if I could do something like:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<QObject*,std::function<void()>,std::function<void>>>> connections = {
  std::make_tuple(mySlider, std::bind(&QSlider::sliderReleased,mySlider, std::bind(&Foo::onSliderChanged,this)),
  .
  .
  .
};
```

And then call it like this:

```
for(auto &&e : connections)
  connect(std::get<0>(e),std::get<1>(e),this,std::get<2>(e));
```

However, when I do this I get an error that there is a substitution failure and a `std::function<void()>` cannot be converted into a function pointer. So decide to change it up and create actual function pointers like the following:

```
typename void(Foo::*fooFunc)();
typename void(QSlider::*sliderFunc)();

std::vector<std::tuple<QObject*,sliderFunc,fooFunc>> sliderConnections = {
  std::make_tuple(mySlider, &QSlider::sliderReleased, &Foo::onSliderChanged),
  .
  .
  .
};
```

And same thing, I then try to call it:

```
for(auto &&e : sliderConnections)
  connect(std::get<0>(e),std::get<1>(e),this,std::get<2>(e));
```

However this also provides a similar error where there are no conversions. Which doesn't make any sense because now I am actually using a function pointer. Which according to [the connection documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) it should be able to take a function pointer to connect them. So either I am passing it in incorrectly. Or what I am trying to achieve is not possible.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your  question to provide a [mcve].  Also show any error messages verbatim.  For what it's worth you pass a `QObject*` as the first arg to `connect` but the second arg is of type `void(QSlider::*sliderFunc)()` -- a `QObject*` is not implicitly convertible to a `QSlider*`, and the last arg you pass is a pointer to a `Foo` member function which needs to be called against a valid instance of `Foo`.

Comment: @G.M. I can edit it to provide a MRE. However, Qt examples are rather difficult to create MRE's because they require at least 3 files in order to reproduce it. And in this case, I would need at least 4. So I can leave instructions on how to reproduce it.

Comment: mre or [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) means that you need to work a little to reduce the code for your question to a minimum. I think that a single header with a QObject derived class, and a main.cpp source would be enough to build and illustrate your question and fulfill the mre requirements.

Comment: In addition, I don't agree (or I don't understand) your motivations. It seems better in your scenario to use the old string (`char*`) based syntax of `QObject::connect` that is evaluated at run-time.

Comment: @Pedro honestly it is just to make the code look cleaner on the constructor side. Right now I have 20+ lines of code that all say `connect(slider, sliderFunc, this, fooFunc)` for sliders, qSpinboxes, and qdoublespinboxes. So my constructor is rather large. Again, it's just an asthetic look. It looks cleaner to call a function that has a two liner in it to build the connections than it does to slap 20+ connections in a constructor.

Comment: But you want to move the mess to somewhere you declare and initialize the vector, which needs to be a c++ source (which will produce nasty error messages when compiled). If you use the old string based syntax you could initialize the vector from a plain text (or XML) external file. The compiler won't check your connections, though.

Comment: @Pedro No, they are private `std::vectors` within my class Foo. You are correct, I moved the mess there. But my source file is the one that builds the connections. It's just preference. And I figured it out thanks to G.M's comment. I intend to write the answer in the morning when I'm not laying in bed. But they were right, my QSlider is not a QObject. As soon as I updated my tuple to take a QSlider* instead of a QObject* it compiled and connected just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at G.M's comment I realized they were correct. A `QObject*` is not a `QSlider*` and therefore when trying to call the function `QSlider::sliderReleased` it couldn't connect the two because `QObject` does not have a slider. So once I changed that in the vector of tuples the code compiled just fine.

ex:

```
typedef void(Foo::*fooFunc)();
typedef void(QSlider::*sliderFunc)();
typedef void(QSpinBox::*spinFunc)();

const std::vector<std::tuple<QSlider*, sliderFunc, fooFunc>> sliderConnections = {
  std::make_tuple(slider1, &QSlider::sliderReleased, &Foo::onSlider1Changed),
  std::make_tuple(slider2, &QSlider::sliderReleased, &Foo::onSlider2Changed),
  std::make_tuple(slider3, &QSlider::sliderReleased, &Foo::onSlider3Changed)
};

const std::vector<std::tuple<QSpinBox*, spinFunc, fooFunc>> spinConnections = {
  std::make_tuple(spin1, &QSpinBox::editingFinished, &Foo::onSpin1Changed),
  std::make_tuple(spin2, &QSpinBox::editingFinished, &Foo::onSpin2Changed),
  std::make_tuple(spin3, &QSpinBox::editingFinished, &Foo::onSpin3Changed)
};
```

These will be private members in whatever class you are in charge of. And then in the constructor, instead of having 6 lines of `connect(object,SIGNAL,object,SLOT)`, you can then put them into a function and call them like:

```
for(auto && tup : sliderConnections)
  connect(std::get<0>(tup),std::get<1>(tup),this,std::get<2>(tup));
```

This successfully connects all the objects to their appropriate functions. Again, it's personal preference. I was just wondering if there was a way and G.M pointed me in the correct direction.